# How to pass data to openGL functions correctly in Rust

Tags: opengl, rust

I'm trying to abstract openGL in Rust. I use [glutin](https://crates.io/crates/glutin) to communicate with openGL ([here](https://github.com/ZaninDavide/ready_to_rust_opengl) is the code I started with). I'm having problems abstracting Uniforms in fact they randomly get `-1` as location (the same code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't).

I checked if the program was in use and it was so I started wondering if there is a problem in the way I send the data to openGL:

```rust
// value is initialised here

let name = name.to_string();
let location;
unsafe {
  location = gl.GetUniformLocation(program.get_id(), name.as_ptr() as *const GLchar);
};

match value {
  UniformType::Float(v) => unsafe {
    gl.Uniform1f(location, v);
  },
  UniformType::Float4(v) => unsafe {
    gl.Uniform4fv(location, 1, &v[0]); 
  },
  UniformType::Texture(tex_id) => unsafe {
    gl.Uniform1i(location, tex_id);
  },
  UniformType::Mat4x4(v) => unsafe {
    gl.UniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, gl::FALSE, &v[0]);
  },
  _ => {
   panic!("Uniform::new This uniform type is unknown");
  }
}

// this scope ends and value if freed
```

Is it a problem the fact that `value` gets freed right after the call to gl.Uniform? If yes, why? I read online that only the draw calls are asynchronous.

---

**Edited: Debugging**

The uniforms are actively used inside the shaders.

Gives the right number of active uniforms counting even those that got `-1` as location:

```rust
let mut param = 0;
unsafe {
  gl.GetProgramiv(program.get_id(), gl::ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, &mut param);
}
println!("Number of active uniforms: {}", param);
```

Always gives `'no error'`:

```rust
let err;
unsafe {
  err = gl.GetError();
}
match err {
  gl::NO_ERROR => {
    println!("Uniform '{}': no error", name);
  }
  gl::INVALID_VALUE => {
    println!("Uniform '{}': invalid value", name);
  }
  gl::INVALID_OPERATION => {
    println!("Uniform '{}': invalid operation", name);
  }
  _ => {
    println!("Uniform: '{}' error: {}", name, err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found the problem:

```rust
// getting a CString from name
let cname = std::ffi::CString::new(name).expect("CString::new failed");

let location;
unsafe {
  location = gl.GetUniformLocation(program.get_id(), cname.as_ptr());
}
```

(sometimes I tend to forget that I'm working with bindings)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [GetUniformLocation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glGetUniformLocation):

> This function returns -1 if *name​* does not correspond to an active uniform variable in *program​*, if *name​* starts with the reserved prefix "gl_", or if *name​* is associated with an atomic counter or a named uniform block.

So you're not error-checking your gl calls, and it looks like there are cases where you're calling `GetUniformLocation` incorrectly, which could account for "sometimes it works, sometimes it does not".

Comment: I asked openGL for errors useing gl.GetError() but it returns GL_NO_ERROR even when I get location -1 and clearly I get errors if there are (I managed to get GL_INVALID_OPERATION by violating the "gl_" prefix rule).