# OpenGL gl::GetUniformLocation fails to locate uniform only in certain cases

Tags: windows, opengl, rust

I'm kinda stuck. I have a program abstraction to locate uniforms for me. I have a fragment shader with a float uniform *elapsed*, and a vertex shader with a mat4 uniform *projection*.
The helper function is defined as followed:

```rust
pub fn find_uniform(&mut self, name: &str) -> Result<(), UniformError> {
    if let Some(_) = self.uniforms.get(name) {
        return Ok(());
    }

    let target_location = unsafe { 
        let location = gl::GetUniformLocation(self.program_id, name.as_bytes().as_ptr() as *const i8);
        let error = gl::GetError();
        if error != gl::NO_ERROR {
            return Err(UniformError::new(true, error));
        }

        location
    };

    if target_location < 0 {
        return Err(UniformError::new(false, UNIFORM_NOT_FOUND));
    }

    self.uniforms.insert(name.to_string(), target_location);

    return Ok(());
}
```

If I use the helper function to look for **only** elapsed or if i look for both with native gl calls it works:

```rust
// No error
if let Err(e) = program.find_uniform("elapsed") {
    eprint!("Failed to find elapsed, probably loading wrong shader. err: {}", e);
    return;
};

// OR
unsafe {
    let location1 = gl::GetUniformLocation(program.program_id, b"elapsed".as_ptr() as *const i8);
    println!("{}", location1); // 0
    let location2 = gl::GetUniformLocation(program.program_id, b"projection".as_ptr() as *const i8);
    println!("{}", location2); // 1
}
```

But if I use my helper function for both it fails to find whatever i look for first:

```rust
if let Err(e) = program.find_uniform("elapsed") {
    // Enters error branch here
    eprint!("Failed to find elapsed, probably loading wrong shader. err: {}", e);
    return;
};
        
if let Err(e) = program.find_uniform("projection") {
    eprint!("Failed to find projection, probably loading wrong shader. err: {}", e);
    return;
};
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, the conversion to `name.as_bytes().as_ptr() as *const i8` is unsafe and depends on memory layout. Rust strings are not C-strings and are not null terminated by default. Use `std::ffi::CString::new();` to ensure the string null-terminated. So your current program depends purely if you get lucky in having a null byte after your byte strings.

The following code should work:

```rust
let target_location = unsafe { 
    use std::ffi::CString;
    let c_name = CString::new(name).expect("Convert to c-string");
    let location = gl::GetUniformLocation(self.program_id, c_name.as_ptr());
    let error = gl::GetError();
    if error != gl::NO_ERROR {
        return Err(UniformError::new(true, error));
    }
    location
};
```

See also:
[How to pass data to openGL functions correctly in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339027/how-to-pass-data-to-opengl-functions-correctly-in-rust)

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess rust has all characters sequential in memory and therefore it fails to find when I put more in the total string buffer?

Comment: The C function will just go ahead and read until the next 0-bye, which can be anywhere. Strings in rust don't use 0-bytes to define the end but have a length associated with it, hence you must convert explicitly to a C string before doing a C-call.